# How to set another field value based on other select field in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select

I have an array of objects, say

```js
const countries = [
  {
    "country": "Afghanistan",
    "region": "Asia"
  },
  {
    "country": "Albania",
    "region": "Europe"
  },
  {
    "country": "Algeria",
    "region": "Africa"
  }
];
```

I have 2 input fields, Country and Region. If user selects the country using select option, I need my region field to be automatically set to the corresponding region of that object.

```html
<div class="form-group stylingtext mt-3">
  <label for="" class="pb-2">Movie Country</label>
  <select 
    class="form-select" 
    aria-label="Default select example" 
    formControlName="movie_country"
  >                           
    <option 
      *ngFor="let country of countries" 
      [value]="country.country"
    >
      {{country.country}}
     </option>
  </select>
</div> 

<div class="form-group stylingtext mt-3">
  <label for="" class="pb-2">Movie Region</label>
  <input
    class="form-control rounded-5"
    formControlName="movie_region" 
    required
  >
</div>
```

I also tried (change) event in select and used ngmodel in the region input-area. But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with this?

ex: If I select "Algeria" in the country, I want "Africa" in the region input-area.

Answer (score 0):

You can try watch for the country value changes like that:

```
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup.controls.movie_country.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  ).subscribe(
    country => this.formGroup.controls.movie_region.patchValue(country.region)
  )
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Where `formGroup` is name of your FormGroup control. And use subject `destroy$` to cancel your subscription.

Comment: Do we have any method to do with property binding or something with change event?

Comment: property is binded with `formControl`